# Ansible extract substring from multiline string containing url

Tags: regex, ansible

I'm trying to extract a substring from a multine string with Ansible regex without success.

I have this ouput from an excuted command (`teleport users add`):

> "stdout": "Signup token has been created and is valid for 3600 seconds. Share this URL with the user:\nhttps://main-proxy:3080/web/newuser/d32ed2bc0ebb0084a381123e3eff0bfa\n\nNOTE: make sure 'main-proxy' is accessible!"

I would like to extract juste the token. Here: `d32ed2bc0ebb0084a381123e3eff0bfa`.

I registered the output in a result variable, and I'm trying to extract the token without success:

```
- set_fact:
    signup_token: '{{ result.stdout | regex_replace("^(?s)^https:\/\/.*\/(.+).*?$", "\\1") }}'
- debug: msg={{ signup_token }}
```

What's the right regex and syntax?

Comment: The regex should be `(?s).*https://.*/([^\r\n]+).*` and perhaps, `{{ result.stdout | regex_search('https?://.*/(.+)') }}` will also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex `(?s).*https://.*/([^\r\n]+).*` works right as I expected.

And also yes I could have tried getting **the last 32 characters from the second line of standard output** but I prefere to be agnostique from token lenght if it changes, so a regex to extract the token id from output is the right way for my case now.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use so complex regular expression? Take 32 chars of `[0-9a-f]` after `/`.

```
- set_fact:
    signup_token: "{{ mystr | regex_search(qry) }}"
  vars:
    qry: '(?<=\/)[a-f0-9]{32}'
```

Use sites like https://regex101.com/ to test your expressions.